# Rails Routes with Model Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am adding a blog to my site, so I created a model bpost, with variables title, content, and category. In the bpost model, I overwrote the to_param function:

```
def to_param
  {#id #title}.parametrize
end
```

So now all urls look like: /bposts/2-to-be-or-not-to-be, where "to be or not to be" is the title (2 is an example id).

I want instead the urls to look like: /:category/2-:title. I tried:

```
resources :bposts, :path => :category
```

OR
    match ':category/:id-:title', :to => :controller => :bposts, :action => :show

but neither seem to work. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the guides for routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

i guess what you want to have is a nested resource like

resources: :category do
  resources: :bposts
end

i think that `:bposts` is a bad name... make it `posts` or `blog_posts`.

another thing for you to look at is the gem-friendly id: https://rubygems.org/gems/friendly_id